# MySQL Server Will Not Turn Off

Tags: mysql

I am attempting to turn off my mySQL server on my mac. I went up to system preferences and attempted to turn it off manually. The "Stop MySQL Server" button will not respond. So I tried this:

```
sudo kill mysqld
```

That killed it and then it restarted about four seconds later. I need to turn this off. Any suggestions? I had previously installed XAMMP, but I uninstalled it earlier today.

Answer (score 0):

Find the PID of your application. You can do that by typing either `pd -ax` or `top -u`. Locate your application/process and indicate the PID. Another way you can locate your PID is by simply opening the Activity Monitor.

To kill that process, use `sudo kill -9 7872` where "7872" will actually be your PID, I was just using that as an example.